# How to define dictionary anchor before Ansible Playbook?

Tags: ansible, yaml

I use default variables a lot along my playbook, and I would love to define a dictionary with default variables before playbook definition in a way like in the following example:

```
# Playbook defaults
vars: &default_vars
  servicename: "{{ job.params.servicename }}"
  core_site: "{{cluster.config['core-site']}}"
  hdfs_site: "{{cluster.config['hdfs-site']}}"
  yarn_site: "{{cluster.config['yarn-site']}}"
  mapred_site: "{{cluster.config['mapred-site']}}"
  # ....

# Playbook 
- name: Install and Configure Namenode 
  hosts: HDFS.Namenode 
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    <<: *default_vars 
    componentname: Namenode
  roles:
    - role: roles/hadoop
```

But it seems that according to YAML syntax I can't define both dict and list on the top level.
How can I define default vars anchor right before Ansible Playbook?

Comment: What "*list on the top level*"? Can't see any in your code and can't imagine what you meant, `vars` is always a dictionary.

Comment: @techraf, I meant that if I start YAML as a list (like any other playbook is), then it is a list on the top level. If I start YAML as a dict, then it is a dict. I cant mix up both dict and list definition in same yaml-file. I tryed here - http://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/, but then I get something like "expected <block end>, but found '-'", and this is obvious , cuz list cant follow dict.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a "dummy" play containing only the vars definitions. Variables will be discarded as play-scoped, but anchor will remain defined:

```
- name: Playbook defaults
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: false
  vars: &default_vars
    my_var1: value1
    my_var2: value2

- name: Install and Configure Namenode
  hosts: myhosts
  vars:
    <<: *default_vars
    my_var3: value3
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: my_var1
```

Result:

```
ok: [myhost1] => {
    "my_var1": "value1"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put default values to the role defaults file (`defaults/main.yml`). For more information see [Playbooks best practices](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_best_practices.html#directory-layout).